# How to decode Transaction to just get program id called in web3.js experimental

Tags: web3.js

I want to get programId called in a Transaction with the new experimental web3.js.

Legacy

```
const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from('serializedTransaction....', "base64");
const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
const accountKeys = transaction.message.staticAccountKeys;
accountKeys.forEach(key=>console.log(key)); // this would get the program id
```

Experimental branch

```
const swapTransactionBuf = Uint8Array.from(
  Buffer.from('serializedTransaction....', "base64")
);
const transaction = getTransactionDecoder().decode(swapTransactionBuf);
```

with the experimental, I'll just get `Cannot convert transaction with addressTableLookups`

Comment: The error message that you've quoted in your question is not from the experimental line of `@solana/web3.js` but is from a library called `@solana/compat`. Can you supply a bit more of the code around the experimental example so that we can debug what's going on?

Comment: @steveluscher I just tried again and i think the correc method im looking for is `getCompiledTransactionDecoder()`

sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-vyrdvy?file=index.js

Comment: Does that mean that you fixed the problem, and you're good now, @Zheng Yu? If not, update your question and we'll keep debugging.